# Connecting QTP and Mainframe

Tags: vbscript, qtp

Can any one share how we can connect QTP and Mainframe and validate values from Mainframe Screen?
In My Project I want to connect QTP and Mainframe to compare the values from Application and Mainframe screen.How can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need Terminal Emulator plugin enabled to automate Mainfame application using QTP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Please let me know how we can connect Mainframe in code wise using VB Script

Comment: You can not automate mainframe applications (by finding the objects of the mainframe application) using VBScript without QTP/UFT.

Comment: @VinothS Why don´t you merge your comments into your answer ;)